# Assign an int to a string value after opening a csv file in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm new in python and just learned how to use pandas. I have a csv file called Data.csv that has a value of A or B in the last column

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('filelocation/Data.csv', header = None)

last_col = data.iloc[0:208, 60]
print(last_col)
```

The last column looks like this:

```
A
B
B
A
A
```

My problem now is that I want to assign an integer to the strings (i.e. A = 0 and B = 1) such that if I again load the last column the results would be:

```
0
1
1
0
0
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `df[0]=pd.factorize(df[0])[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your mapping in a dictionary and pass to `.replace()` like so:

```
In[2]: import pandas as pd
  ...: 
  ...: df = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B'])
  ...: 
  ...: # inspect before
  ...: df
  ...: 
Out[2]: 
   0
0  A
1  B
In[3]: # define mapping for the translation
  ...: mapping = {
  ...:     'A': 0,
  ...:     'B': 1,
  ...: }
  ...: 
  ...: # apply the mapping
  ...: df[0] = df[0].replace(mapping)
  ...: 
  ...: # inspect after
  ...: df
  ...: 
Out[3]: 
   0
0  0
1  1
```